# Access-granted applications not listed on user console

Tags: keycloak

I created a client called `my-app` in `myrealm` realm, the `Always Display in Console` and `Consent Required` options of which are also enabled.

According to the help message of the `Always Display in Console` option which says:

> Always list this client in the Account Console, even if the user does not have a active session.

And then, I logged in the user console via `<mydomain>/auth/realms/myrealm/account`, but there is no application named `my-app` in the application (only one named `Account Console` listed here).

Is there anything I missed for the configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried filling out the `Base URL` field on the client, and the application was listed in the Application List in the Account Console.

Comment: Great! It works. I reported an issue about it [KEYCLOAK-18679](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18679)